# PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed

Tags: pgfplots, pdf, nodes, contour

I used a C++ function my teacher gave us to create some `ppm` files, which I then converted to the `eps` format using an online resource for use in my report. However, these images are causing problems. This had never happened before, so I don't understand why it's happening now.

The error message isn't the issue so much as the fact that this somehow conflicts with the `contour` package and prevents me from adding contours to nodes in `pgfplots` that desperately need them (since they overlap the plots they're supposed to be labeling).

I tried using `\pdfminorversion=7`, which made the error message go away (although TeXworks still hitches when it reaches the images while generating the PDF) but didn't fix the problem with `contour`. I can't omit these images and I can't seem to get `contour` to work unless they're gone.
I also tried simply adding more ticks to the plot, but they overlap with the others. Two of them overlap with each other, which is hard to fix by simply shifting their vertical placements (which I also already attempted).
There's no way to place the nodes on the plot without them either being too far from the points they're supposed to be labeling, or on top of the lines.

I'm not even sure how to create a MWE for this, since you'd need the actual image files themselves to create the problem. In fact, it's when I tried creating a MWE for what I thought to be a `contour` problem that I realized these images were the real culprit.

Is there some way around this problem that doesn't involve omitting the images altogether?
Also, if you have an idea on how I can create a MWE for this problem, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: if you made the eps, how were the pdf made?

Comment: I only "made" the ppm and used an online resource to convert them to eps. The PDF was generated by TeXworks, I assume. I'm kinda new to LaTeX, so this is all uncharted territory for me.

Comment: Are you sure the eps is an eps? If you open it in an editor, what does the first line say?

Comment: The first line says ```%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0```. I can't be sure it's an eps because I don't know enough about the format, but the online resource claimed it would convert the ppm to an eps. I've used it in the past and it never gave me any trouble, so I didn't bother to question it.

Comment: then I would say that without the actual file and a test document for a real test it is not possible to help you.

Comment: How can I provide the actual file? Is there some way to upload it here?

Comment: the internet is full of possibilities ...

Comment: I'm not allowed to post links because my account is too new, hence the question. I'd rather not get banned for trying to bypass that account limitation.

Comment: I didn't know that new users were forbidden from posting links. However, I do know that users with at least 10 reputation points can post 'more' links. So, if I upvote your question, then you should have no trouble posting one...

Comment: Thank you. I'm uploading the images and creating a MWE. I'll update the question with the relevant info as soon as it's done.

Comment: I figured out the problem as I worked on the MWE. The culprit was an option for the ```contour``` package that I read one should use while I was searching for practical examples. The person who posted it neglected to mention there are certain restrictions when using that option, which is why it rendered the package ineffective. With that option removed, the package works as expected. Still, thank you both for the help.